# changing package name of the project , stopped app

Tags: android, android-studio, package, renaming

I have changed package name of the project but when I tried to rum it shows the message "Unfortunately  App has stopped".I had followed the following steps to change my package name [Android Studio Rename Package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804093/android-studio-rename-package/29092698#29092698)

My logcat error is as follows:
08-04 18:08:54.806  27626-27626/com.Bubbles E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) cannot open file at line 30046 of [9491ba7d73]
08-04 18:08:54.806  27626-27626/com.Bubbles E/SQLiteLog﹕ (14) os_unix.c:30046: (2) open(/data/data/com.confec/databases/confec.sqlite) -
08-04 18:08:54.807  27626-27626/com.Bubbles E/SQLiteDatabase﹕ Failed to open database '/data/data/com.confec/databases/confec.sqlite'.
    android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCantOpenDatabaseException: unknown error (code 14): Could not open database
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeOpen(Native Method)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:209)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.open(SQLiteConnection.java:193)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.openConnectionLocked(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:463)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:185)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnectionPool.open(SQLiteConnectionPool.java:177)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openInner(SQLiteDatabase.java:806)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.open(SQLiteDatabase.java:791)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:694)
            at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(SQLiteDatabase.java:669)
            at com.Bubbles.database.DataBaseHelper.checkDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:95)
            at com.Bubbles.database.DataBaseHelper.createDataBase(DataBaseHelper.java:58)
            at com.Bubbles.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:93)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5990)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1106)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2278)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2390)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:151)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1303)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5257)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
08-04 18:08:54.809  27626-27626/com.Bubbles D/AndroidRuntime﹕ Shutting down VM
08-04 18:08:54.809  27626-27626/com.Bubbles E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main

I appreciate any help and thanks in advance. :)

Comment: No error in Logcat..

Comment: Are you using google analytics?

Comment: Nope...Im using android studio for development of app

Comment: Do i need to change  database name too?.. I didn't made any changes in database name

Comment: What is the new package name you set?

Comment: Did you change the applicationId in build.gradle as well?

Comment: Bubble is my new package name..and i changed applicationId in build.gradle too